# Pass a parameter with struts 2 action

Tags: struts2, parameter-passing, struts-action

How can I pass a parameter with struts 2 action?.

Here is my code.

```
<s:form>

    <s:select name="menuItem" list="menuItems" listKey="menuItemID"
        listValue="menuItemName" headerKey="" headerValue="--MenuItems--"
        cssClass="selectbox_bg2" id="select"
        onchange="handleChange(this.value)" />

    <s:textfield name="select_value" id="select_value" />

</s:form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function handleChange(value) {

    window.location = "callMyAction?ValueToSubmit=" + value;

}

</script>
```

My Question is How can I get this parameter(value) in my action class.
and passing a parameter to return jsp page.

Thanks..

Comment: have you tried `request.getParameter("ValueToSubmit");` ?

Comment: this is not a servelet or jsp.. action is forwarded to action class using a struts.xml..

Comment: I can read that in your title. So you are saying that in Struts 2 Action, you cant use `request.getParameter("..")` ?

Comment: It is not a common practice for struts 2 mvc architecture..

Comment: What action this form submits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 Just create "valueToSubmit" variable in your action class with public getter and setter

```
public MyAction extends ActionSupport {

  private BigDecimal valueToSubmit;

  public String execute{
    ... some code.....
  }

  public BigDecimal getValueTOoubmit(){
    return valueToSubmit;
  }

  public void setValueToSubmit(BigDecimal valueToSubmit){
    this.valueToSubmit = valueToSubmit;
  }
}
```

Struts2 ParametersInterceptor will get the parameter value from request and set it to action parameer automaticly.

2 To read this parameter in the action result jsp page just use some struts tags

```
  <s:property value="valueToSubmit"/>, 
  <s:textfield name="valueToSubmit"/>, 
  etc..
```